# Connect to the same server on MooMoo.io?

Tags: moomoo.io

I've found moomoo.io recently and wanted to test it out with my friends. But we can't quite hit the same server.

I guess it's something similar like Agar.io, where you find the socket in your browsers console and connect to it there, but I can't quite figure it out here.

Edit: There has been an update with the party button being added. It worked for us some moments ago, but it has a bug at the moment that renders it useless. Regardless of that, I'm looking for a way to force join the same server without using the provided party option.

Comment: I performed a rollback of your edit, if you feel that the game has updated to make this easier, you can post that as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect to the same server as your friend, go to the url and check what number it says after

> http://moomoo.io/?party=

so if it says

> http://moomoo.io/?party=54.68.175.241

then tell your friends to go to that address. You could also just send them the URL and they would be able to connect to the same server. This is assuming that the server was not full, of course.

There is a "create party" button in the upper right corner, but I don't think it works. Just use the method described above.

Comment: The create a party is a recent feature, but it is broken atm. Everyone recieves "server is full" if they try to join someones party.

Comment: @DushDushDush So, does the suggested method work for you? If so, it would be really helpful if you could "accept" my answer so others know it worked for you.